# Invoking one class from another

Tags: java, swing, class

I am trying to learn java and surely I am not getting something.
For the sake of simplification let us assume I have two classes, class A and class B. I want to call class B from class A and when I do that I need that anywhere I right click (right button) inside class A to get the pop-up menu as defined in class B. The code is the following:

**CLASS A code:**

```
package test1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class A {

    JFrame frame;
    Toolkit toolkit;

    A () {

        frame = new JFrame("A class");
        setDimm(frame);
        B b = new B();


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void setDimm(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame=frame;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        toolkit = frame.getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((size.width-frame.getWidth())/2, (size.height-frame.getHeight())/2);

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new A();
    }
}
```

**and CLASS B code is:**

```
package test1;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

public class B extends JFrame {

    JPopupMenu menu;
    JMenuItem addRow, removeRow;

    B(){
        menu = new JPopupMenu();
            addRow = new JMenuItem("Add row");
            removeRow = new JMenuItem("Remove row");

            // Adding two action listneres just to test the clicking on the items
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    System.out.println("Add rows. Testing and it works");
                }
        }); 

        removeRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Remove rows. Testing and it works");
                }

        });
            // end of action listeners

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.getButton() == e.BUTTON3) {
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }
            });

        menu.add(addRow);
        menu.add(removeRow);
        add(menu);
    }
}
```

I added class B inside class A but it does not work. 
I tried creating a JPanel and adding it to that, still nothing. 
I tried creating a B instance with a JPanel or JFrame parameter and then inside class A invoking class B and putting a JPanel or JFrame from class A but still nothing. 
I tried to create a main method inside class B and it works to create the right click but inside class B and that's not where I want it.

What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks and all the best!

Comment: You create a new `B` in `A` but never do anything with it like set it visible or anything.

Comment: I tried also b.setVisible(true) and still nothing. I tried also creating a panel inside A and inside B and adding the menu's to those panels. Nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `JPopupMenu` has to be in class `B` ? Can you not simply create it in class `A` ?

Comment: I thought about it and no. It shouldn't be in class B because if I put it in class B then I would have to declare many variables again that are not in class B. So the only curiosity now is related to the functionality of the code itself. Why it is not showing up, that's why it bothers me the most. For learning purposes, not for functionality point of view. Thanks